iTerm has full disk access but “ls: Operation not permitted” on remote system
I've read about this issue. I see SIP and TCC are in play. I have 2 Mac laptops both running Sonoma. On each, iTerm has full disk access and SIP enabled.
Local to each of them in iTerm I can access all folders without problems. But when I SSH from one to the other, I can't access SIP-protected folders.
Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?
[macos1]$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
[macos1]$ ls Downloads/
a_bunch
of_my
files_as
expected

[macos1]$ ssh macos2
[macos2]$ ls ~/Downloads
ls: Operation not permitted


UPDATE: Adding more data:
[macos1]$ type bash
bash is /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
[macos1]$ /opt/homebrew/bin/bash -version | head -1
GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin23.2.0)
[macos1]$ ls -lOd Downloads
drwx------+ 40 myuser  staff  - 1280 Apr  5 10:04 Downloads
[macos1]$ xattr -l Downloads
[macos1]$ ls -lOd /usr
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root  wheel  restricted,hidden 352 Mar 20 23:13 /usr
[macos1]$ xattr -l /usr
com.apple.rootless:

[macos1]$ ssh macos2
Last login: Sat Apr  6 18:53:55 2024 from 10.0.0.18
[macos2]$ type bash
bash is /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
[macos2]$ /opt/homebrew/bin/bash -version | head -1
GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin22.6.0)
[macos2]$ ls Downloads
ls: Downloads: Operation not permitted
[macos2]$ ls -lOd Downloads
drwxr-xr-x@ 45 myuser  staff  - 1440 Apr  6 18:47 Downloads
[macos2]$ xattr -l Downloads
xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'Downloads'
[macos2]$ cd Downloads
[macos2]$ ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
[macos2]$ exit
logout
[macos1]$ touch hmmmm
[macos1]$ scp hmmmm macos2:
hmmmm

The 'hmmmm' file is present on macos2:Downloads/hmmmm
hmmmm

The Downloads folder isn’t SIP protected.  What shell are you running?

You're right, I see that Downloads isn't SIP protected now.. I've updated my original post with more data.

What happens if you issue the command cd ~/Downloads then ls?

Under Catalina, I have the following with respect to ssh. Probably is /usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper.



This is it. Thank you! I added /usr/sbin/sshd and gave it full disk access. But that isn't what solved it. sshd-keygen-wrapper was in the list, but disabled. As soon as I enabled that for full disk access, it fixed it. I wonder what it is about sshd-keygen-wrapper. I would assume sshd would have been the key here. I think this started recently, in the last 3 months. I wonder what changed.

I was just looking at that in Ventura. I have full disk access for sshd-keygen-wrapper, but not for sshd. I suppose I should edit my answer.
